# How to get episode name where the character appeared for the first time? (Rick&Morty api)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, react-hooks

I'm trying to create Rick&Morty page like the original [Rick&Morty-api](https://rickandmortyapi.com/)

But I have problems with the **First seen in:** line , where you can see on which episode the character appeared for the first time.

I've used useEffect to get all characters and rendered them. It was the easest part, but I don't understand how to get name of episodes , where character appears for the 1st time. And It should work on each page, when I change my page by my pagination. Maybe I should match episodes id with characters id. I really want to work out this problem.
So please direct me somehow:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a list of episodes which should contain the episode id and name.  You already get the episode id from character.match, so you should be able to do something like:

```
let episodeName = episodes.find(e => e.id == character.episode[0].match(/\d+/)[0]).name;
```

For the particular context of your output jsx, I think this will work:

```
<h3 className="character_location">
  {episodes.length > 0 && episodes.find(e => e.id == character.episode[0].match(/\d+/)[0]).name}
</h3>
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the attention . I've just tried your code , but I got Uncaught TypeError: episodes.find is not a function. Where it supposed to be written?

Comment: Hi, your getAllEpisodes function doesn't seem to get all episodes.  I had assumed that `episodes` was an array, because it's being initialized as an array `[]`.  Without having all episodes in an array, my code won't work.

Comment: Maybe you have another solution?:)
Anyway, thanks

Comment: Your update solution hasn't any errors, but unfortunately it still doesn't work.